# Making websites responsive how?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For about 3 months I've started studying as a Software Developer. We need to make a website for a driving school for a project with a team of four people. I've got a 14-inch laptop and they have a bigger one, when we send the files to each other and open it, the websites looks not the way it should look. The image is not full size, but on the laptop that wrote it it does. The text is mostly not responsive.

The image on the home page is called: #homeAfbeelding
The text on it is called: #tekstHome, #tekstHome2 & #tekstHome3

the text under the gold color: #tekstreden etc...

Any idea how to make it responsive? It would really help me and my team with this study. I've tried many ways but it doesn't work for me.

Thank you! `

```
<title>Rijschool Wummy</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="easydrive.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="rijschoolafbeelding.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```
<nav> 


    <div id="navNaam"> 
    <a href="easydrive.html"><img src="img/rijschoolafbeelding.png" id="logo" width= 60%>  </a>



    <li><a href="rijlessen.html"> Rijlessen </a> </li>
    <li><a href="tarieven.html"> Tarieven </a> </li>
    <li><a href="diploma.html"> Opleidingen </a> </li>
    <li><a href="geschiedenis.html"> Over ons </a> </li>        
    <li><a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> </li>
    <li><a href="login.html"> Inloggen </a> </li>

</nav>
    </div>

    <div id="achtergrondHome"> 
    <img src="img/snelweg13.gif"  id="homeAfbeelding"> 
    <h2 id="tekstHome"> Een rijbewijs halen is makkelijk bij ons. </h2>
    <p id="tekstHome2"> Snel uw rijbewijs halen? </p>
    <p id="tekstHome3"> Dat kan bij onze goed opgeleide rijinstructeurs! </p>
    <button onclick="afbeeldingKnop()" id="afbeeldingKnop"><a href="proefles.html">Meld je nu aan voor een gratis proefles! </button></a>

</div>

<div id="containerHome"> 
<h1 id="rijschoolTekst"> Rijschool Wummy </h1>

    <hr>

    <br>


<div id="titelReden">

<h3 id="r1"> Hoge slagingspercentage </h3>

<h3 id="r2"> Vrijblijvende proefles en opleidingsadvies </h3>


 </div>

 <div id="tekstReden"> 

 <p id="a1"> "Een professionele rijschool met een zeer hoog slagingspercentage – dat is de beste omschrijving voor Rijschool Wummy uit Amsterdam. Al jarenlang realiseren wij een  hoog slagingspercentage en hebben we aandacht voor íedere leerling. Belangrijk : slagingspercentage van Rijschool Wummy is gebaseerd op meer dan 10 eerste examens per jaar. Natuurlijk kun je ons hoge slagingspercentage eenvoudig terug vinden via de website van het CBR. </p>

<p id="a2"> "Na afloop krijg je een persoonlijk opleidingsadvies voor het behalen van je rijbewijs. Om zoveel mogelijk uit je autorijlessen te halen krijg je altijd rijles van dezelfde instructeurs/-tices en in dezelfde lesauto. Voor de rijlessen komt autorijschool Wummy je thuis ophalen en wordt je ook weer afgezet. Met onze Rijlesplanner heb je overal online toegang tot je planning, betalingen, vorderingen en theorie. </p>


</div>

<div id="titelReden2"> 

<h3 id="r3"> Faalangst rijlessen of rijangst rijlessen? </h3>
<h3 id="r4"> Modern rijlesprogramma </h3>

</div>

<div id="tekstReden2">
<p id="a3"> Voor jou hebben wij echte gespecialiseerde instructeurs en hypnotherapeuten die je kunnen helpen met het op een geruste manier behalen van je CBR-examen voor de auto! Veel mensen hebben last van een of meerdere van de onderstaande kenmerken en hebben om die reden veel moeite met het rustig rijden tijdens het CBR-examen, terwijl het tijdens de lessen eigenlijk altijd wel goed gaat. 

<br> 
    <br>

    Autorijschool Wummy heeft getrainde instructeurs die leerlingen met faalangst zeer goed kunnen begeleiden en weten wat te doen om dit soort angsten te laten verdwijnen. Het is belangrijk om vanaf de eerste rijles te werken aan deze spanning, zodat u geruster het rijexamen kunt afleggen. Naast dat onze instructeurs gespecialiseerd zijn in het geven van faalangsttrainingen bieden wij daarnaast ook de mogelijkheid tot lichte en gevorderde hypnotherapie vooraf aan het rijden. Hier gaat wel altijd een gesprek aan vooraf om de obstakels in kaart te brengen. Hierdoor weet de instructeur wat de juiste behandelmethoden zijn om toe te passen. Desgewenst kan hier nog een tweede instructeur bij aanwezig zijn.
  </p>

<p id="a4"> Wij hebben een heel moderen rijlesprogramma. Het nieuwste van het nieuwste. Alles is van 2019. Dat betekent dat wij in de meeste gevallen een gratis herexamen hebben, je hebt altijd en overal toegang tot je theorie. Waardoor je kunt leren wanneer je wilt. Zo verhogen we de slagingspercentage elk jaar. Je kan online je facturen bekijken, betalen, afspraken inplannen en je agenda bekijken voor je volgende rijles. Wel handig!

    <br> 
        <br>
Autorijschool Wummy maakt gebruik van haar eigen digitale Xpress omgeving. Via dit portaal hebben leerlingen inzicht in de gehele rijopleiding. Denk aan zelf de rijlessen inplannen en aanleren, rijles vorderingen bijhouden, voorbereiden op CBR rijexamens en betalingen verrichten. Leerlingen die gebruik maken van deze dienst hebben aantoonbaar minder rijlessen nodig, waarmee de weg naar een rijbewijs een stuk minder duur wordt gemaakt. Dit hebben we te danken aan de kwaliteit en service die onze rijschool vanuit Amsterdam verleend!
</p>
</div>

<hr> 

</div>
```

[image: On my laptop]

[image: on smaller screens]

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;

    body{
        font-family: Arial, Open-Sans;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden; 
        height: 0;


    }

    li{
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-family: Arial, Open-Sans;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;

    }

    a:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #navNaam{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position: relative;
        top: 30px;
        right: 80px;
        bottom: 20px;

    }

    #logo{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        bottom: 40px;
        left: 100px;

    }

    #tekstHome{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 350px;
        left: 330px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px grey;

    }

    #tekstHome2{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 340px;
        left: 430px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px grey;
    }

    #tekstHome3{
        position: relative;
        bottom: 330px;
        left: 330px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px grey;


    }

    #afbeeldingKnop{
        position: relative;
        background-color: dodgerblue;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 30%;
        height: 40px;
        border: 8px turquoise;
        bottom: 330px;
        left: 420px;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }

    #homeAfbeelding{
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 400px;

    }

    #rijschoolTekst{
        text-align: center;
    }

    #titelReden{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        position:relative;
    }

    #tekstReden{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    #r1{
        left: 110px;
        position: relative;
        color: gold;

    }

    #r2{
        right: 105px;
        position: relative;
        color: gold;

    }

    #a1{
        max-width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
    }

    #a2{ 
        max-width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        right: 30px;
     }


     #titelReden2{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
     }

    #tekstReden2{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
     #r3{
        left: 70px;
        position: relative;
        color: gold;

     }

     #r4{
        right: 190px;
        position: relative;
        color: gold;

     }

     #a3{
        max-width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
     }

     #a4{
        max-width: 500px;
        position: relative;
        right: 30px;
     }


     #containerHome{
        bottom: 240px;
        position: relative;
     }
```

Comment: can we modify your you html code?

Comment: You need to read up on media queries to make a website responsive: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Hint: You can test different screensizes in Chrome by Opening the Developer Tools (F12) and pressing Ctrl + Shift + M.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution to this is adding bootstrap to your project. You can add it the same way you have added font awesome cdn link. Once you have added bootstrap you can use its grid structure to take care of the responsiveness. By using bootstrap you can make it responsive for all resolutions. To check the responsiveness you can use mobile view in the inspector of your browser. To study botstrap check the link below:

**https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/**

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to make site responsive. Go through the following link for a better explanation
[Responsive web design using media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Regarding the image part just add `img{max-width:100%}` So that it will adjust on all type of devices according to the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I addition to [Tayyab Ullah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10995166/tayyab-ullah)'s answer: Bootstrap is an *opinionated* framework, i.e. it comes with lots of predefined Components, Colors, Sizes etc.

If you want to rely on your own Design, there are also *unopinionated* frameworks like [Kickoff](http://trykickoff.com/) and [Tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/what-is-tailwind/), which are also more lightweight.